# unable to upload multi files through django serializer

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework, django-views

I can upload single files at a time but cant upload multiple files at once. Any idea how can I upload multifiles ?

my *models.py*

```
class Posts(models.Model):
   
    title = models.CharField("Title", max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    text = models.TextField("Text", blank=True, null=True)
    url = models.URLField("URL", blank=True, null=True)
    video_url = models.CharField("Video Url", max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey("profiles.HNUsers", on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)


    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Posts"


class VideoPost(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey("profiles.HNUsers", on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    video = models.FileField("Post Video", blank=True, null=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField("Timestamp", blank=True, null=True, auto_now_add=True)
    text = models.TextField("Description text", blank=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "VIdeo Posts"
```

my **serializers.py**

```
class VideoPostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = VideoPost
        fields = (
            'user',
            'text',
            'video',
        )
```

and my views.py

**postman**
[image]

**Extended question :**
updated my VideoPostSerializer

```
class VideoPostSerializier(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    video = VideoPostSerializer(many=True, required=False)
    class Meta:
        model = VideoPost
        fields = (
            'user',
            'text',
            'video',
        )

    def create(self, validated_data):
        videos = validated_data.pop('video')
        post = VideoPost.objects.create(**validated_data)
        if videos:
            videos_instance = [VideoPost(post=post, video=video) for video in videos]
            VideoPost.objects.bulk_create(videos_instance)
        return post
```

Now I am facing this error in my POSTMAN
[image]

**Postman new error**
[image]

Comment: can you add your Post Video model

Answer (score 1):

The point is that if you want the main model to have a lot of images or videos. You cannot add it as a field in the main model. You need to create a new model that will be associated with the main

for example i can show you my code with multi FileField upload

my models

```
class VideoPost(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey("profiles.HNUsers", on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField("Timestamp", blank=True, null=True, auto_now_add=True)
    text = models.TextField("Description text", blank=True))


class PostVideo(models.Model):
    video_post = models.ForeignKey('VideoPost', models.CASCADE, related_name='post_video')
    video = models.FileField('Image', upload_to='post/images/'
```

my serializers:

```
class PostVideoSerializer(serializer.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = PostVideo
        fields = '__all__'


class VideoPostSerialzier(serialzer.ModelSerializer):
    post_video = PostVideoSerializer(many=True, required=False)
    class Meta:
        model = VideoPost
        fields = '__all__'

    def create(self, validated_data):
        videos = validated_data.pop('post_video')
        post = VideoPost.objects.create(**validated_data)
        if videos:
            videos_instance = [PostVideo(post=post, video=video) for video in videos]
            PostVideo.objects.bulk_create(images_instance)
        return post
```

now you just need to call serializer.save() in your view

but you need a specific request like:

```
{
    'text': 'sometext',
    'user': 20
    'post_video': [IMAGEDATA1, IMAGEDATA2]
}
```

Also I wrote it blindly so there may be some mistakes but i hope you will have it as an example to rewrite your code

UPDATED - PostsSerialzier and request example

postman body example [image]

UPDATED 2 - updated models and serailzers

Comment: Thanks but I am getting 'ListSerializer' object is not iterable and if you dont mind can you show me how to post through POSTMAN please ?  I am updating my postman request in my post thanks

Comment: updated my answer, sorry second image key must be  same = post_image (in picture i make mistake - post_mage)

Comment: still having the same error .. updated in my post .. thanks a ton for your help

Comment: fixed that but got list index out of range error

Comment: I think you have bad model architecture. Should Posts and Video Posts be linked?
You have only one video field in a video post, so a video post can have one video. Do you need a video post to have a lot of videos?

Comment: yes . I do . fact is , I am new to this  and cant figure out where I am making mistakes

Comment: updated models and serialziers in my answer - also in postman send your vidoes with key - post_video

Comment: The point is that if you want the main model to have a lot of images or videos. You cannot add it as a field in the main model. You need to create a new model that will be associated with the main

Comment: sorry for bothering you like this , you are really helpful .. I am updated my questions on my post under extended question : and provided new postman screenshot. can you help me figuring out what I am doing wrong here ?

Comment: i write 2 models VideoPost and PostVideo. And write 2 serailzers PostVideoSerializer and VideoPostSerialzier. You In  VideoPostSerializer using video = VideoPostSerializer(many=True, required=False) you using the same serialzer. I am in VideoPostSerialzier using filed post_video = PostVideoSerializer(many=True, required=False)

Comment: i hope you get what you need

Comment: actually I am still figuring out but thanks a lot for your kind help .. I really appreciate it

Comment: Hi, sorry to bother you again , I am getting this following error  -- "KeyError at /api/posts/post/video/
'post_video'  ".. any idea why this is happening while I am trying to post through POSTMAN .. thanks in advance

Comment: I solved it and refreshed my code but not being able to solve new error. I am updating my postman error in my post titlng postman error

Comment: as you can ee i am getting null while posting

Comment: its getting harder and harder)). Can you upload your project to github or gitlab?

Comment: sorry for troubling you this much. lets see what I can do .. do you have discord ?